# Is this an appropriate place for questions about esoteric languages?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I realize that as per the ask/don't ask the answer is "no", but if I go to StackOverflow how many people are going to answer a question about Fish or CJam?

I feel like questions about golfy languages maybe should be on topic here.

Comment: I think in general no, but there are exceptions, e.g. Tips for Golfing in [Language]. SO definitely does not want golfing tips questions.

Comment: @Alex I have seen these around the site and they are helpful, but I think they are different in that the question is essentially "Here are tips" and answers are tips, it's not formatted in a way that you can ask a question -- unless commenting a question is appropriate of leaving a question as an answer is okay (which seems to be a complete perversion of the SE model).

Comment: I think we need a *Golf Overflow* site. That would be where we ask for golfing tips

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think they are on topic here, because where do you draw the line for what counts as an esoteric language? The fastest way to get help with these languages is probably [in the PPCG main chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

But I would actually suggest you *do* ask them on Stack Overflow (provided it would be a good question for SO if it was about a "normal" language), and then leave a link to the question in our chat. Seeing the [Brainfuck](https://stackoverflow.com/?tags=brainfuck) and [Befunge](https://stackoverflow.com/?tags=befunge) tags, there is definitely precedent for questions about esolangs on SO.

Note that **"provided it would be a good question for SO if it was about a "normal" language"** is really important here. SO does not like questions about golfing code, be it in an esoteric language or not. If you want to ask for advice in golfing something (in any language), this belongs here on PPCG with the [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) tag.

Comment: Similarly, there are lots of English word/letter games and riddles on [Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), but you don't go there for questions about using the language.